# How to display time range on iteration?

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to run a for loop that has to loop 8 times. On each iteration I want the loop to increment the value by +1 hour.

The final output should be in this time format:

opening hours:
08:00, 09:00, 10:00,11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00,16:00

In this case `timediff` mentioned in the `for...loop` holds the value of 8.

```js
var minutesToAdd = 60;
var currentDate = new Date("2022-04-10 08:00:00");
var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + minutesToAdd * 120000).toLocaleTimeString();

for (let i = 0; i < timeDiff; i++) {
  console.log(futureDate, 'futureeee date');
}
```

Comment: I've created a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you, please update the snippet so it contains a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is not clear what the question is? If you have a problem with your code, please explain what it is... I do notice that you never update `futureDate`, so you'll print the same thing over and over again.

Comment: HI, Im trying to display a time range between 08:00 - 16:00 ....  starting from 08:00 i want to increment the time with 1 hour each iteration. And the final has to be the ouput of a time range the format: 08:00, 09:00, 10:00,11:00, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00,16:00

Comment: So what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Because the code im using is not working :/

Comment: *"not working"*: please update the question to explain what you mean with "not working", and what you have done to fix it (without success).

Answer (score 2):

Your code never updates `futureDate` in the loop. Also, when you expect to print 08:00 in the example, you should print `currentDate` when no minutes have been added yet.

I would also suggest you use the native function `setMinutes` and `getMinutes` to add a number of minutes to a date object.

You say that `timeDiff` has a value of 8, but then you say you want 9 outputs (8:00 ... 16:00), so you'll need an additional iteration.

Finally, to get the hh:mm output format, there are several solutions. One is to choose a locale that uses a format that is close to what you need, and express you want the *short* format (without seconds):

```js
let timeDiff = 9; // One more to also output 16:00
let minutesToAdd = 60;
let currentDate = new Date("2022-04-10 08:00:00");

for (let i = 0; i < timeDiff; i++) {
  console.log(currentDate.toLocaleTimeString("en-SE", { timeStyle: "short" }));
  currentDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() + minutesToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can then use a simple for-loop to iterate from `0` up to and including `timeDiff`, incrementing each iteration by `1`.

```js
for (let hours = 0; hours <= timeDiff; hours += 1) {
  // ...
}
```

Instead of a starting date we'll start with a timestamp `Date.parse("2022-04-10 08:00:00")`. This allows us to add the time from the loop to the timestamp and create a new date.

```js
const date = new Date(currentTimestamp + hours*HOURS);
```

To only display the time I've taken the liberty of using the solution provided by the [answer of trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71999174/3982562).

```js
const MILLISECOND = 1                , MILLISECONDS = MILLISECOND;
const SECOND      = 1000*MILLISECONDS, SECONDS      = SECOND     ;
const MINUTE      = 60*SECONDS       , MINUTES      = MINUTE     ;
const HOUR        = 60*MINUTES       , HOURS        = HOUR       ;

const timeDiff = 8;
var currentTimestamp = Date.parse("2022-04-10 08:00:00");

for (let hours = 0; hours <= timeDiff; hours += 1) {
  const date = new Date(currentTimestamp + hours*HOURS);
  console.log(date.toLocaleString(undefined, { timeStyle: "short" }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, just what I needed, really helped!